# Нужен совет как вытянуть данные из PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

Есть PDF фаил, в котором есть таблица с данными. 
Таблица вида "Name - Data" и так в столбик. Фото прилагается[image: Образец] 
Пытаюсь найти способ реализации как по ячейке с именем вытянуть её данные.
PDF я весь считал пытался как то через регулярки вытянуть. Но косяк в том что понять где его данные и какие данные вытягивать не понятно т.к pdf считывается и выдает обычный текст (данные могут менятся в Data). Пробовал как то декомпрес pdf сделать но что то не удачно. Софта мало на эту тему. А узнать внутрение теги не могу. Кто что знает подскажите :) Буду очень блогодарен
Например есть ячейка Supplier надо вытянуть её данные Aker Solution...

Answer (score 2):

С pdf все плохо. Перепробовал все что можно - конвертацию в Word, в Excel, текстовый файл. Самый многообещающий способ - конвертация в html и парсинг с помощью web-драйвера [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: хм мысль интересная. Спасибо. Испробую:)

Comment: в этом случае довольно неплохо воспроизводится разметка (шрифты, таблицы, цвет, заголовки), что позволяет довольно легко находить нужные элементы. Если бы еще не было косяков...

Comment: Да только теперь надо разобраться как сперва через код конвертировать фаил закинуть в папку с программой например, и сохранить путь к сохраненному файлу. А потом просто обратиться к нему и найти нужное. У меня пока чето не все в голове слаживается в кучу

Comment: Какой код? Для конвертации нужен всего лишь Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Мне надо реализовать через код. Что бы список файлов закинул. Оно считала поля с файла вытянуло их и записало в отдельный фаил. Но с PDF файла считать ячейки таблицы не понимаю как сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с PDF я использовал опенсорсную библиотеку [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). Очень мощная, но чтобы что-то вытащить из PDF приходится глубоко вникать, как устроена его структура. Если у вас разовая задача - возможно, это будет чересчур, но если нужно настроить импорт данных на регулярной основе - самое то, что нужно.

Comment: Да только у меня задача такая. Есть например 10 таких таблиц разных с разными данными. Мне надо их вытянуть и записать в другой документ. Как бы найти регуляркой поля можно.Но как  понять где лежат данные которые относятся к данному полю. Косяк весь в этом.

Comment: PDF по своей сути сильно отличается от DOC или, допустим, XLS. В нем, чаще всего, нет ни таблиц, ни ячеек, а есть текст, векторные линии и растровые вставки. Поэтому соотнести конкретный текст с конкретным полем в большинстве случаев возможно только по координатам. Но и с координатами все очень непросто, т.к. иногда для разных элементов используется своя координатная система, заданная матрицей трансформации. И еще очень много зависит от источника, т.к. разные программы формируют PDF очень по-разному.

Comment: У меня еще такая идея появилась. Надо проверить. А если попробовать в xml конвертировать? Интересно как он будет выглядеть внутри

Comment: И xml я пробовал. Что-то лучше, чем в html, что-то хуже. Но в обоих случаев присутствуют косяки. Иногда данные перемешаны. В общем, веселья там хватает.

Comment: Да PDF вообще веселый формат